# How can I append a new datafile in an existing InnoDB tablespace?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I want to add a new data file in an existing InnoDB tablespace so that entry of data is smooth in case it hits its 4GB limit.

Comment: Specify "existing tablespace" type, table(s) engine(s), and server settings relative to tablespaces.

Comment: @Akina its InnoDB

Comment: Specify "existing tablespace" type and server settings relative to tablespaces.

Comment: @Akina its both innodb_file_per_table and general tablespace scenario. Server settings is localhost, I am not sure about it though.

Comment: When `innodb_file_per_table` is set the tablespace for a table is a solid file, and it cannot be extended with another file it seems. If 4Gb limit is a filesystem one - move table's tablespace to another volume.

Comment: What 4GB limit?  Are you using a computer from the 20th century?  Are you really talking about "tablespace" or did you mean "table".  If the former; explain why you are using tablespaces.

Comment: @RickJames The size limit is granted by MySQL server for Windows OS. I am talking about a datafile not the  memory of a computer or server. THE DATAFILE's LIMIT IS 4GB which you cannot go further or extend it as *Akina pointed out (Look above your comment)

Comment: @devilboy477 - What filesystem?  FAT32?  I think you need to change to NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Reformat the disk to be NTFS.  Caution:  This destroys all data, so you would need to do a major backup and restore.

Plan B:  Turn off `innodb_file_per_table`, go into `my.cnf` and configure the main tablespace in a way I have not seen used in more than a decade -- namely something like `ibdata1:3G,ibdata2:3G,ibdata3:3G,ibdata4:3G,ibdata5:3G`.  That way, you are pre-specifying the partitions and InnoDB (unless it has forgotten how) will be able to handle tables of arbitrary size (> 4GB) if they are in that tablespace.  Finally, `ALTER TABLE foo ENGINE=InnoDB` to *move* the table into that tablespace.

Yuck.  Turn back the clock because of Windows.

Comment: LOL. It's a great approach for more distributed and partitioned database but we are going in a monolithic approach. It seems what I am trying to find does not exist :)

Comment: @devilboy477 - That kludge in my.cnf is to get around the 4GB _file_ limit that existed in several OSs two decades ago.  It should allow the files to be in separate disk partitions.

Comment: I think what you told above is for MySQL. Isn't it ?